# anaconda navigator stuck on "adding featured channels" (Windows 10)

Tags: anaconda, navigator

Very often, (once every week or two), I noticed that my Anaconda navigator fails to launch and it ultimately requires me to uninstall and reinstall Anaconda.

As can be seen in the image attached, once I attempt to open the navigator in Anaconda command prompt, it gets stuck on "adding featured channels..."

I've tried editing, deleting, and replacing "condarc" file, and followed the advice from this page (https://support.anaconda.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024042553-Anaconda-Navigator-Issues-Launching-or-Initializing) as well.

None worked for me.[image]

Also, I've tried following the troubleshooting steps suggested here (https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10461) but did not work for me.

I am convinced that there must be a better way to deal with this than having to uninstall and reinstall the entire package.

Answer (score 0):

You can try disconnecting the network and rebooting anaconda.It works for me.